# Partially define Struct definition in ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm not well-versed with the Python-C interface and I am working with a C SDK.

There is this struct called `NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT` and I only need to retrieve `dwSize` and `byPicNo` from the API callback function.

In my callback function (Python) I will use the `memmove` function to copy the result memory block. Is it a good practice to only define a partial `struct` and still be able to get the actual results that I want? Like how I defined below

```
class NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("dwSize", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("byPicNo", ctypes.c_byte)
    ]
```

From Documentation: **NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT** (The actual definition is much longer)

```
struct{
  DWORD                    dwSize;
  DWORD                    dwMatchNo;
  BYTE                     byGroupNum;
  BYTE                     byPicNo;
  BYTE                     bySecondCam;
  BYTE                     byFeaturePicNo;
  BYTE                     byDriveChan;
  BYTE                     byVehicleType;
  BYTE                     byDetSceneID;
  BYTE                     byVehicleAttribute;
}NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT, *LPNET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplicity's sake, when referring to structure sizes, I will ignore the (4 byte default) memory alignment, and act like they would be **one byte** aligned, so that the size of a structure is equal to the sum of its members sizes.

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes
> >>>
> >>> class Struct0(ctypes.Structure):  # Your NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT structure, with a shorter name
> ...     _fields_ = [
> ...         ("dwSize", ctypes.c_uint),
> ...         ("byPicNo", ctypes.c_byte)
> ...     ]
> ...
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> class Struct0Pack001(ctypes.Structure):
> ...     _pack_ = 1
> ...     _fields_ = [
> ...         ("dwSize", ctypes.c_uint),
> ...         ("byPicNo", ctypes.c_byte)
> ...     ]
> ...
> >>>
> >>> print(ctypes.sizeof(Struct0))
> 8
> >>> print(ctypes.sizeof(Struct0Pack001))
> 5
> ```

When **the caller** (the *SDK* from your other questions) of your callback function will invoke it, it will attempt to populate its *NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT* argument (to the memory pointed by the argument if the argument is a pointer (most likely), or directly on the stack if it isn't), and therefore to write `sizeof(NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT)` (***16***) bytes - as it expects that structure.

But you'll only be passing ***5*** bytes, and as a result the *SDK* will try writing outside its "allowed" memory zones resulting in ***Undefined behavior***. You'll probably get *segfault*s (*Access violation*s).

Also, considering that the program will pass the above phase, since you eliminated some of the fields (*dwMatchNo*, *byGroupNum*), you won't get correct data in your *byPicNo*, but *dwMatchNo*'s 1<sup>st</sup> byte.

So, **never go for shortcuts like this one**, well except you really know what your doing and also what the code that deals with them does - which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Hmm, looking at *dwSize* member, I'm thinking of *MS* structures (e.g. [[MS.Docs]: OSVERSIONINFOEXW structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_osversioninfoexw)) whose 1<sup>st</sup> member is their size and it needs to be set accordingly before passing the struct (pointer) to the *API* that is populating its (relevant) members. It would be interesting to check this scenario as well. But in any case, it can't possibly work with the proposed *NET_ITS_PLATE_RESULT*.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation!